# Spark flatmap is giving Iterator error

Tags: apache-spark

I am getting error if I apply a flatMap over a JSONArray to JSONObject
If I am running on my local(laptop) from eclipse, it runs fine, but when running on cluster(YARN), it gives weird error.
Spark Version 2.0.0

Code:-

```
JavaRDD<JSONObject> rdd7 = rdd6.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<JSONArray, JSONObject>(){
    @Override
    public Iterable<JSONObject> call(JSONArray array) throws Exception {
        List<JSONObject> list = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length();list.add(array.getJSONObject(i++)));             
        return list;
    }
});
```

error-log:-

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.pwc.spark.tifcretrolookup.TIFCRetroJob$2.call(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/Iterator;
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:124)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$IteratorWrapper.hasNext(Wrappers.scala:30)
    at com.pwc.spark.ElasticsearchClientLib.CommonESClient.index(CommonESClient.java:33)
    at com.pwc.spark.ElasticsearchClientLib.ESClient.call(ESClient.java:34)
    at com.pwc.spark.ElasticsearchClientLib.ESClient.call(ESClient.java:15)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:883)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:883)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1897)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1897)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Do you have Scala 2.11 installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Spark 2.0.0, the function inside a `flatMap` call must return an `Iterator` instead of `Iterable`, as the release notes state:

> Java RDD’s flatMap and mapPartitions functions used to require functions returning Java Iterable. They have been updated to require functions returning Java iterator so the functions do not need to materialize all the data.

And here is [the relevant Jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3369)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in 2.1.0. Did this change somewhere in the minor version? I have spark-core_2.11:2.1.0 on my classpath and when I try this I get Error:(31, 25) java: method flatMap in class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD<T> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: scala.Function1<java.lang.String,scala.collection.TraversableOnce<U>>,scala.reflect.ClassTag<U>
  found: (x)->Array[...]tor()
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) U
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)